# Low water pressure to kitchen sink after installing new water heater

Tags: water

I installed a tankless water heater and now the kitchen sink has low pressure.

I checked the aerator and cleaned it out, still low pressure. 
I filled a container with water with the aerator both On and Off of the hose, 47 seconds to fill with aerator on, 43 seconds to fill with it off.

Need some advice on where else to check - other than about the aerator, please.

**used PEX tubing and shark bite unions for new water heater.  Connected back to main water lines (cpvc).

Comment: [How do I fix the low water flow of my kitchen sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49373/how-do-i-fix-the-low-water-flow-of-my-kitchen-sink)

Comment: What manufacturer and model of tankless heater did you install? What size container did it take 45 s to fill? Almost any tankless water heater will have a lower flow rate than a tank. Is the lower flow rate only on hot or is it on cold also?

Comment: Low flow is only to kitchen sink, otherwise pressure is fine throughout the house.  Eco smart 27 model water tank.  The container size was roughly 3/4 gallon, I didn’t actually measure the container.   The flow rate issue is both hot and cold water.  I planned to check the water flow directly from the shutoff valves before it goes to the faucet.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'd guess that maybe changing out the water heater may have knocked some accretions loose which found their way to the line going to the sink and stuck inside the faucet. Checking from the shut-off valves should tell you.